# images or vml windows 10 mail/outlook 2007+ dissapear randomly on f.e. window resize

Tags: html, image, outlook, rendering, vml

When opening a html mail with its code written for Windows 10 mail client (I assume Outlook 2007 +also) which uses Word engine i can see all images (img tag) or vml language controls rendered properly. But often i see some controls images missing when opening the same e-mail the second time or on resizing windows 10 mail window. Because of this resizing of a loaded e-mail window it doesn't seem have anything to do with some delays in loading elements via Internet, especially that a vml control doesn't use any outside recources. The html mail code is based on tables. Here's an example code with sometimes visible or invisible element:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="273" border="0"  style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0px;">
    <tr>
        <td width="273" valign="middle" align="center" bgcolor='#f7941d' style="background: #ffffff">    
          <!--[if gte mso 12]>
            <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://example.com/" style="height:46px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:273px;" arcsize="15%" strokecolor="#f7941d" fillcolor="#f7941d">
              <w:anchorlock/>
              <center><font size="4" color="white" face="Verdana,sans-serif" style="text-decoration:none;font-size: 20px;line-height: 46px"><b>BUTTON TEXT <font class="greaterthan" style="position: relative;top: -1px;">&gt;</font></b></font></center>
            </v:roundrect>
          <![endif]-->                        
          <a href="https://example.com/" style="text-decoration:none;display:block;color: #fff;background: #f7941d;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;border-radius: 10px;"><font size="5" color="white" face="Verdana,sans-serif" style="text-decoration:none;font-size: 20px;line-height: 46px;mso-hide:all;"><b><font style="display:none;">&nbsp; &nbsp;</font>BUTTON TEXT <font class="greaterthan" style="position: relative;top: -1px;">&gt;</font><font style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></font></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr><td height="30"></td></tr>
</table>
```

This question seems to be really important to everybody having outlook 2007+ in mind.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this answer can be not enough, but in my case it helped when a VML button got position:relative - i didn't see it display inproperly even once. But for windows 10 mail you cannot use position: relative for non VML elements  so what may help somebody to simplify her/his code as much as possible - dissapearing of elements may not be as often (as in my case), using less nested elements might help. This is what i noticed so far. A piece of code can be written from scratch different way also if nothing works.

Well to remember, in some situations using position for vml elements may not position an element as expected. But i had success with a vml button. position:relative;top:1px; this is what i did.